# Deploy Angular 14 app to Heroku (error: ng not found)

Tags: angular, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a simple Angular 14 app on Heroku. However, after deploying, I encountered an error that I'm struggling to resolve.I attempted to resolve the issue by moving the "@angular/cli" package from devDependencies to dependencies in the package.json file, but unfortunately, it did not resolve the problem. Additionally, I added the "--configuration production" flag to the "ng build" command to build the app for production, but the issue still persists.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "sample",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "engines": {
    "node": "16.19.0",
    "npm": "9.7.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "npm": "^9.7.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

and the error

```
2023-06-08T11:07:47.608269+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=farbod-app.herokuapp.com request_id=79c3cd02-9040-4fc3-b445-d053f1dc9a20 fwd="95.90.194.43" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2023-06-08T11:08:17.357967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2023-06-08T11:08:20.096156+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2023-06-08T11:08:21.594123+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-08T11:08:21.594139+00:00 app[web.1]: > sample@0.0.0 start
2023-06-08T11:08:21.594139+00:00 app[web.1]: > ng serve
2023-06-08T11:08:21.594139+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2023-06-08T11:08:21.600857+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: ng: not found
2023-06-08T11:08:21.720196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2023-06-08T11:08:21.751677+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```